# Can I burn wood in this fireplace?

Tags: fireplace

I have what appears to be a manufactured fireplace with a metal flue (rather than masonry). It currently burns gas, and I assumed that's all I could burn, but I noticed on its product placard that it was suitable for solid wood fuel **or** gas.

Is it safe to have the gas pieces removed and burn wood in here? Are there any potential concerns with the flue/chimney?

The fireplace itself appears to be ceramic sheets embossed with a texture similar to brick. The gas/hvac guy I use said it would be safe, but I wanted a second opinion.

I have attached a photo of the placard inside the fireplace.[image]

Comment: Have you tried contacting a chimney expert?  Look in the phone book (or ask google), for "Chimney repair", or "Chimney cleaning", etc.  Chances are any company that installs or services fireplaces and chimneys, will be able to tell you if you can safely burn wood or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The firebox may be rated for solid fuel, but is the chimney constructed to handle the extra heat and the possibility of having a flue fire from soot and creosote deposits?

A natural gas flue is not a solid fuel flue. If the chimney construction was skimped on to save money, then no.

If your HVAC tech has inspected the chimney and found it up to proper standards, then maybe.

Comment: Have a look at my comment to @mikes post. I'm not sure the HVAC guy would have reason to have expertise in this area (but I also don't know who WOULD).

Comment: Haven't had any luck finding a Temco/Temtex TBF 42-3 installation manual. I hate extrapolating anything from later models, but it sounds like they're supposed to be a complete installation system with a double wall flue. Per the later model manual: "Use only TEMCO manufactured components, listed under 8" Diameter Chimney System (on the prior page), when installing a TEMCO fireplace. Substituting other manufacturers' components for, or altering TEMCO parts will void the UL listing and the TEMCO warranty." Do you have any local wood heating specialists in the area?

Comment: Looks like the company evaporated during the Econolypse of 2007.

Comment: To answer your question about local providers, I'm not sure to be completely honest. I will check Angie's List, though I'm not entirely sure of the terms to search for.

Comment: "wood stove fireplace chimney installation and inspection" plus your nearest large town name should flush something out of the woodwork. Chimney cleaning and inspection is a vital part of meeting insurance requirements.

Comment: I have spoken with a chimney expert in the area and he's assured me that only one type of flue can be attached to the fireplace, and that it is safe to use for wood. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Enjoy the heat!

Answer (score 1):

If you trust the gas /HVAC you have been using his opinion should matter most. He has seen it first hand and is in the best position to make a judgement. You will want to see if a manual is available to see what needs to be done to convert it burning wood. Be sure to perform the regular maintenenace that a wood burning stove requires.

Comment: My issue is that I'm not really sure if this is something that an HVAC guy would know about (i.e. the safety of the chimney). I'm just not sure who WOULD know the answer to that. He didn't seem concerned at all with the chimney; I'm not sure he even looked at it.